# Passenger fail running on Apache -- Web application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

i have a problem with passenger + apache, i already set up a virtualHost...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.temazo.es
  PassengerEnabled on
  PassengerAppRoot /home/handra/ruby/temazo
  RailsEnv development
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/handra/ruby/temazo/public
  ErrorLog /home/handra/ruby/temazo/log/fails
  <Directory /home/handra/ruby/temazo/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```

Now if i go to www.temazo.es and click on 'About your application’s environment', that return me this error...
http://www.temazo.es/rails/info/properties

But if i execute rails server... and i go to http://www.temazo.es:3000/ , that works perfectly, and returns me all ruby conf.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your gemfile, you should have this line :

```
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

Uncomment it, and run `bundle install`, then deploy your app again.

You need a javascript runtime installed on your server so the javascript can be compiled and ran.

Comment: Thanks, now works perfectly,,, sorry 4 the question, but is my first day in RoR. :)

Comment: By the way, you should change ``RailsEnv development`` to ``RailsEnv production``, no one needs to see your error messages. Please consider accepting my answer is everything is alright now, enjoy RoR.